# Why is my UL sub-menu taking the background of it's grandparent?

Tags: html, css, background, navigation

I'm working on a menu and on small screens I have it using gradients for backgrounds. There are 4 levels to this sub-menu, and each have their own color backgrounds. But for some reason my 4th level sub-menu is taking the background color of the 2nd sub-menu (it's grandparent) instead of the color it should be, which is pure white. It's so weird, this problem skips the 3rd sub-menu. I've tried as many work-arounds as I can think of, and even adding !important to the 4th level css hasn't fixed it. Below is the jsFiddle and the code. Am I missing something?

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6c5ba0t/)

**CSS (for small screens)**

```
   #navbar {
                background-color: #29568F !important;
        }

                .nav-tabs {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                width: 98.5%;
                background-color: #29568F;
                margin: 0px 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                list-style-type: none;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
                font: 18px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
                border: 3px solid #29568F;
                }

                #menu-icon {
                    width: 200px;
                    display: block;
                    float: left;
                    text-align: left;
                    border: 0px;
                    border-bottom: 0px !important;
                }

                .nav-tabs > li:first-child span { /* This is #menu-icon */
                    border: 0px !important;
                    background: #29568F !important;
                }

                .menu-item {
                    display: none;
                }


                .nav-tabs li {
                    width: 100%;;
                    border-right: 0px;
                    clear: both;
                    list-style-type: none;
                }

                .nav-tabs li span {
                    display: block;
                    border: 0px !important;
                    padding: 10px 2.5% !important;
                    width: 95% !important;
                    position: relative !important;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                }

                .nav-tabs li span {
                    text-align: left;
                    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey !important;
                    background: linear-gradient(#29568F, #3399CC);
                }

                .nav-tabs > li > span:hover,
                .nav-tabs > li .open {
                    background: linear-gradient(#3399CC, #29568F);
                }

                /* -- Arrows -- */

                .nav-tabs .arrow-open {
                    content: url("/images/arrow-up.png");
                }
                .nav-tabs li .arrow-closed{
                    content: url("/images/arrow-down.png") !important;
                }

                /* --- 2nd level submenu -- */

                .sub-menu {
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    clear: both;
                }

                .sub-menu > li {
                    position: relative;
                    left: 0px;
                }

                .sub-menu > li span {
                    left: 0px;
                    text-align: center;
                    background: linear-gradient(#99EEFF, #3399CC);
                }

                .sub-menu > li > span:hover,
                .sub-menu > li .open {
                    background: linear-gradient(#3399CC, #99EEFF);
                }

                /* -- 3rd level submenu -- */

                .drop-menu {
                    display: none;
                    clear: both;
                    width: 100%;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                }

                .drop-menu li span {
                    border: 0px;
                }

                .drop-menu > li > span {
                    border: 0px !important;
                    left: 0px;
                    text-align: left;
                    background: linear-gradient(#C9EAF3, #ffffff);
                }

                .drop-menu > li > span:hover,
                .drop-menu > li .open {
                    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #c9EAF3);
                }

                /* -- 4th level submenu -- */

                .slide-menu {
                    display: none;
                    background: #ffffff !important;
                    border: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    clear: both;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    z-index: 300px;
                }

                .slide-menu li {
                    position: relative;
                    left: 0px !important;
                    width: 98%;
                    border: 0px !important;
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .slide-menu li span {
                    display: block !important;
                    position: relative;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    border: 0px !important;
                }
```

**HTML (sample code to view structure)**

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-tabs">
        <li id="menu-icon"><span><img src="/images/menu-icon.png">Menu</span></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><span>Dogs <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><span>Meet the Breeds<div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                    <ul class="drop-menu">
                        <li><span>Sort A - Z <div class="arrow-closed"></div></span>
                            <ul class="slide-menu">
                                <li>Breeds A - F</li>
                                <li>Breeds G - L</li>
                                <li>Breeds M - R</li>
                                <li>Breeds S - Z</li>
                            </ul> <!-- close slide-menu -->
                        </li> <!-- close Drop-menu item -->
                   </ul> <!-- close drop-menu -->
               </li> <!-- close sub-menu item -->
           </ul> <!-- close sub-menu -->
       </li> <!-- close main menu item -->
  </ul> <!-- close main-menu -->
</div>
```

**NOTE!**

While creating the jsFiddle for this question, I realized that when I only included the css for small screens, the 4th level menu's background was white as it was supposed to be. It wasn't until I included the WHOLE CSS code that it stopped working. Which still doesn't make sense because the 4th level background works in it's normal, large screen state. I don't understand why it would be doing this so if someone would be kind enough to comb through this for me I'd be ever so grateful.

**UPDATE!**

I've been messing with the jsFiddle, and I removed all of the large-screen CSS to try and de-bug it. 4th level menu had a white background. Ok. So I added the 1st level CSS back in, and the 4th level background messed up. Removed it, and added the 2nd level CSS in, and the 4th level background messed up again. But if I added in the 3rd or 4th level CSS for large screens, the 4th level background wasn't affected at all. So the problem is somewhere BOTH in the 1st level and 2nd level CSS. But I don't understand why. I don't have anything inheriting it's parent's css, and none of the code calls for any gradient at all. So weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent a few minutes looking over your code, and i think i found the problem. In your 2nd and 3rd sub-menu you're applying the background to the span tags. But on your 4th menu ( .slidemenu ) you're applying it directly to the ul.

Remove background from:

```
Line: 416
.slide-menu
```

Add background to:

```
Line: 432
.slide-menu li
```

Working fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6c5ba0t/2/)